# How to assign a dynamic property in a model via a SQL query in Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.3 to build an API and I have an model for products. Whenever I retrieve a product, I want to retrieve the product's rating and it's recommended rate. I also have a model for reviews and products have many reviews.

```
$product = Product::where('slug', $slug)->with('reviews')->first()->toArray();
```

Rating is computed by looping through $product->reviews in the controller, adding up the score of each review, then dividing it by the total number of reviews.

```
if (count($product['reviews']) > 0) {
    $i = 0;
    $totalScore = 0;
    foreach ($product['reviews'] as $review) {
        $totalScore = $totalScore + $review['Rating'];
        $i++;
    }
    $product['averageReviewRating'] = $totalScore / $i;
} else {
    $product['averageReviewRating'] = null;
}
```

Recommended rate is computed with a SQL query.

```
$product['recommendedRate'] = round(DB::select("
    select ( count ( if (Recommend = 1,1,NULL) ) / count(*)) * 100 as rate 
    from Review where PrintProduct_idPrintProduct = " . $product['idPrintProduct']
)[0]->rate);
```

This leaves me with $product['averageReviewRating'] and $product['recommendedRate'] with the data I want but seems very sloppy. I would like to just be able to do something similar to this below and have those two values assigned to each object of a collection, than access them via `$product->averageReviewRating` and `$product->recommendedRate` or even not include them in with and have those values eagerly assigned.

```
$product = Product::where('slug', $slug)->with(['Reviews', 'RecommendedRate', 'AverageReviewRating'])->first();
```

Anyone know a way to do this with ORM? I've looked high and low and have not found anything.

Comment: Im on my phone or would leave an example but generally that sort of logic should be on the model. Then you can do a custom attribute on the product model and loop your review records in there. To further improve on that that you could just query the reviews directly using the product model id as the select criteria and perform the average calculation in mysql

Comment: How you are calculating Recommended rate. if you can explain i can give the clean answer using ORM

Comment: @Vikash the query is right in the question. An answer can be agnostic to how I'm doing it though. I just want to run a query and assign the value it returns to a dynamic property every time I call the model.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way

```
protected $appends = [
 'reviews',
 'recommendedRate',
 'averageReviewRating'
];

public function getReviewsAttribute() {
 return $this->reviews()->get();
}

public function getRecommendedRateAttribute() {
 if (count($this->reviews) > 0) {
    $i = 0;
    $totalScore = 0;
    foreach ($this->reviews as $review) {
        $totalScore = $totalScore + $review->Rating;
        $i++;
    }
    return $totalScore / $i;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

public function getAverageReviewRatingAttribute() {
 return round(DB::select("
    select ( count ( if (Recommend = 1,1,NULL) ) / count(*)) * 100 as rate 
    from Review where PrintProduct_idPrintProduct = " . $this->idPrintProduct
)[0]->rate);
}
```

then simply call `Product::where('slug', $slug)->first()->toArray();`

**P.S.** This is just the way you can do, I might miss part of logic or names..

Comment: This is working for now but the only issue is those methods only run when you access the properties so if you call the property in the view technically you're running SQL while rendering the view.

Comment: when you are adding `protected $appends = [
 'reviews',
 'recommendedRate',
 'averageReviewRating'
];` it is appending without accessing to properties

Answer (score 0):

The way to get the sum in Laravel Eloquent is using the Aggregate `sum` and for average `avg`
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#aggregates

If you want to add a custom property to your model for that, you can use

```
class Product {
    function __construct() {
         $this->{'sum'} = DB::table('product')->sum();
         $this->{'avg'} = DB::table('product')->avg();
    }

}
```

**edit:** to set the attributes, you can use the built in function https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/v4.2.17/Eloquent/Model.php#L2551

Comment: Product is a model so you cannot dynamically declare properties in the constructor like that.

Comment: @wwwroth why not? I know pretty sure you can